# menu tab doesn't appears in dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

when i add this code

```
<?php
    add_action('init','registration_my_menus');
      function register_my_menus() {
        register_nav_menus(array(
              'main-menu' => 'Main Menu'
            ));
      }

?>
```

in function.php page in my custom theme then no menu tab is appear in appreance on dashboard

Comment: registration_my_menus != register_my_menus

Comment: Check this helps you. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in `add_action`. You have not properly add the name of function in `add_action`.

Use this code:

```php
add_action('init','register_my_menus');
  function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(array(
          'main-menu' => 'Main Menu'
        ));
}
```

Comment: still no menu is  appear

Comment: See in sub menu of Appearance.

Comment: Dashboard > Appearance > Menus

Comment: the problem is with theme that why menu doesn't appear.